# exctract correlated elements of a correlation matrix

Tags: r, correlation

I have a correlation matrix in R and I want to know how many groups (and put these groups into vectors) of elements correlate between them in more than 95%.

```
X <- matrix(0,3,5) 
X[,1] <- c(1,2,3)
X[,2] <- c(1,2.2,3)*2
X[,3] <- c(1,2,3.3)*3
X[,4] <- c(6,5,1)
X[,5] <- c(6.1,5,1.2)*4

cor.matrix <- cor(X)
cor.matrix <- cor.matrix*lower.tri(cor.matrix)
cor.vector <- which(cor.matrix>0.95, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

`cor.vector` then contains:

```
     row col 
[1,]   2   1 
[2,]   3   1 
[3,]   3   2 
[4,]   5   4
```

That means, as expected, that the vectors 1,2 and 3 correlate between them, and also 4 and 5.

What I would need is to get two vectors `c(1,2,3)` and `c(4,5)` as the final result.

This is a simple example, I am processing large matrices though.

Comment: is it possible that `1-2`, `1-3` are correlated, but `2-3` is not?

Comment: It is not. If 1-2 and 1-3 correlate, then 2-3 have to be included in the same group. It is a particular condition for what I need.

Comment: A naive approach would be to test all pairwise-row-combinations of `cor.vector` via `sum(is.element(i,j))>0` and if they share a common element, then you join them and go on. As there might be probably more efficient ways to get the solution, I do not dare to write this as an answer...

Comment: If x1, x2 are linearly related and x2, x3 are linearly related as well, then isn't x1,x3 automatically linearly related?

Comment: @Arun, I was thinking about the case where `cor(1,2)=0.96`, `cor(1,3)=0.96` and `cor(2,3)=0.94`

Comment: (+1) for the very interesting question. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: @e4e5f4, but in your example, all three pairs are highly correlated. From your first comment, what I thought you were hinting is: cor(1,2)=0.95, cor(1,3)=0.95, cor(2,3)< 0.20 (say, or another lower number)

Comment: @Arun, highly correlated doesn't matter because of the `0.95` threshold.

Comment: DanielFischer, yes, actually I have a couple of 'naive' solutions, but, as you say, maybe somebody knows an efficient way to do it.
Arun, It depends on how you assume that they are linearly related. Actually you are testing its correlation, and with a 95% of condidence.

Comment: @e4e5f4, I see what you mean now. I think it's better to have p-values for measure of significance than to have a hard threshold. If so, then we wouldn't run into problems with your scenario, probably?

Comment: (+1) Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using `igraph` package:

```
require(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(cor.vector, directed = FALSE)
split(unique(as.vector(cor.vector)), clusters(g)$membership)
# $`1`
# [1] 2 3 1

# $`2`
# [1] 5 4
```

What this essentially does is to find the clusters in the graph g (disconnected sets), as illustrated in the figure below. Since the vertices are used to create the graph in the order you entered (from your `cor.vector`), the clustering order also comes back in the same order. That is: for vertices c(2,3,5,1,4) the clusters are c(1,1,2,1,2) with a total of two clusters (cluster 1 and cluster 2). So, we just use this to split using the cluster group.

[image]

Comment: I have run your code with my data and it works perfectly. I also compared the results of your code with the code I developed, that works fine but it is much less efficient, and I need to process lots of data. The results are the same.